# What does this block of code mean? Is it equivalent to window.onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onload

While working on an Angular JS App I found following block of code:

```
(function(){
    // code goes here
})();
```

Is it equivalent to `window.onload` or `document.ready`?

Comment: No. It is called anonymous self-invoking function (function without name).

Comment: @Sumanta736 Immediately Invoked Function Expression aka `IIFE`

Comment: @Tushar is it ok to have this multiple functions like this inside `document.ready`. Does it have cons?

Comment: @Pekka There's no pros of putting IIFE inside the `ready`, the `ready` handler also serves the purpose of IIFE

Comment: @Tushar i see thank you for clarification. I have those for a reason that i dont want a global var so when two function need a var i use that to wrap the 2 functions.Its good to know that it does not harm the flow of code in anyway